# I'm getting /pentaho/saml/SSO HTTP 404 Not Found when configuring SAML 2 SSO in Pentaho

Tags: single-sign-on, pentaho, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to configure SAML 2 SSO in Pentaho 8.1 with WSO2 Identity 5.3.0 Server. I have followed theses guides:

- https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.1/Setup/Administration/User_Security/Implement_Advanced_Security/Set_Up_SAML_for_the_Pentaho_Server
- http://docplayer.net/19831592-Saml-installation-and-integration-best-practices-updated-1-4-2016-authors-jonathan-jarvis-pedro-teixeira-and-joao-l-m.html

When I try to access Pentaho, the browser goes to the Identity Server Login page:

[image]

and after successfully login I'm correctly redirected to http://localhost:7070/pentaho/saml/SSO, but all I get is a HTTP 404 Not Found:

[image]

/saml/SSO is the filterProcessesUrl of the samlWebSSOProcessingFilter and it's configured in a blueprint.xml file. Also there is no error or exception in the logs.

I don't know where else to look, any idea will be very appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After activating debug for `org.pentaho.platform.spring.security.saml` and `org.springframework.security.saml` packages I could see the exception in the logs:

> org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException:
>   Metadata for entity localhost and role
>   {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}IDPSSODescriptor wasn't found

When looking at the metadata file of the service provider I found that the role it referred to was the `xmlns` attribute of the this tag:

```
<EntityDescriptor xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" entityID="wso2carbon">
```

I changed the value of `entityID` to `localhost` and then it worked.

Edit: The error was in identity provider metadata file.

Answer (score 1):

the saml/sso is actually in your service provider metadata file

you need to upload the catalina and pentaho log to determine the cause of the 404, there are various reasons why that could happen

please make sure your repository.spring.properties is correctly configured for singleTenantAdminUsername

Comment: Alexis there where nothing showing up in logs at that time. When I activated the debug mode  was when I could see an exception. The problem was in the entityID in the IdP metadata file. I forgot to write the solution. Thank you very much!